# Coding example for thrift in C, using files

Tags: c, json, struct, thrift

I've started using thrift for C. I managed to generated the .c and .h files via the compiler. I'm looking to write to a file, preferably JSON. However there are no examples on the apache thrift site. A internet search turns up next to nothing useful. Does anybody have any sample code that I can use? I essentially have a struct has a bunch of ints and char *.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However there are no examples on the apache thrift site. A internet search turns up next to nothing useful.

That's simply not true, we have a [great tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/) covering a great part of the languages. You can find them quite easily via Google. The tutorial code can be found in the [release tarball](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.1/thrift-0.9.1.tar.gz) or in the [Git repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=tutorial;hb=refs/heads/master) as a top-level directory named **tutorial**.

Since you are looking specifically for JSON, I recommend to have a look at the cross-language test client/server, which can be found under `test` or `lib` (a bit inconsistent right now, we are about cleaning that up). AFAIK for plain C there is no JSON available, but for C++ there is.

In order to store things into a file, you basically choose a stream or file transport and the protocol of your choice from the available protocols. It's as simple as (pseudocode)

```
var data = InitializeMyDataStructure();

var trans = new TFileTransport("myfile");
var prot = new TJSONProtocol(trans);

data.write(prot);
```

The support for plain C is somewhat limited yet, but there is all kinds of transports/protocols for C++.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I'm essentially looking to take a C struct, and write to a file in a human readable form. I guess I need to use TFileTransport and TDebugProtocol/TJSONProtocol. I did'nt see any specific example of this. Can you point me to this?

Comment: Also, idea, where to get prebuilt libraries for MacOS and Linux?

Comment: One of the great things about Thrift is, that protocols can simply be plugged in. Again, I encourage you to look at the cross-lang test servers/clients which uses that feature.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'll look at that.

Comment: @JensG Thanks for pointing out that there is an example for C/glib on the apache thrift website. I can't find it. Can you add the link?

Comment: In [this folder](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=tree;f=tutorial/c_glib;hb=refs/heads/master) you'll find the tutorial code. The web site part is (still) [to be added](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3172).